# showing google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-fragments

Am facing a Fatal exception on running google map v2 , i did import google-play-service-lib 
and make an Api from google, and that the mainfest am using :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.getlocation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


<permission
        android:name="com.example.getLocation.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.getlocation.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.getlocation.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 <activity android:name="com.example.getlocation.map"
                              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>    
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyB7rXLp7f3cnZ0sdjqQnCQiPbiPpkNVmPc"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the map layout xml is :

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/the_map"

        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and here is the class activity :

package com.example.getlocation;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class map extends FragmentActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }
 }
```

and the phone am running on version is 2.3.6 ,

Comment: can u post the stack trace

Comment: Add `<meta-data>` tag before closing tag `</application>`.

Comment: @divya its not working also.

Comment: there is mainactivity with button opens map class ,

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Amira/Desktop/mjh.png

Comment: java.langn.oclassdeffound error , couldnt find class map!

Comment: Declare your `Map` class in manifest.

Comment: i did but still not working

Comment: the previous activity opens this by this code: 
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
 
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, map.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
 
  });

Comment: Update your post above with the new manifest you are using

Comment: i did update the manifest

Comment: the error in logcat is in : android.support.v4.app.fragment.instantiate

Answer (score -1):

Try different code

link:http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Here completely describe about googlemap one thing you always remeber that your googlemap cannot display on emulator it will run on real device but you should first test it on your emulator if no error occur then test it on real phone.